# Downloading file from S3 bucket and converting it back to tar file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the function below to upload file to S3 bucket. When I download the file back I receive the buffer in data.body. How can I convert the buffer to appropriate file?

Is there a generic way to do it. I have searched a lot didn't find any suitable working suggestions, any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks!

```
const uploadContentToS3 = function(fileName,orgName){
    console.log("calling upload content s3")
    fs.readFile(fileName, (err, data) => {
        if (err){
            console.log("err.message: ", err.message);
            return false;
        }

        const params = {
            Bucket: bucketName, // pass your bucket name
            Key: orgName, // file will be saved as testBucket/contacts.csv
            Body: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
        };
        s3.upload(params, function(s3Err, data) {
            if (s3Err){
                console.log(s3Err.message);
                throw new Error(s3Err.message)
            }
            console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`)
        });
    });
}

const fetchContentFromS3 = function(orgName){
    console.log("calling fetch content s3")
        const params = {
            Bucket: bucketName, // pass your bucket name
            Key: orgName // file will be saved as testBucket/contacts.csv
        };
        s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                throw err
            }
            console.log(data);
            fs.writeFileSync('./test.txt', data.Body)
            console.log('file downloaded successfully')
        })
}
```

Comment: What do.you mean by "convert the buffer to appropriate file"? Are you facing any issue or error? Why `writeFileSync` is not working for your use case?

Comment: Write file sync is working but I am not getting back tar.gz file that is extractable. I mean that I have buffer stream and I need to convert the buffer stream to the proper file. Say I have image file or music files, how can I convert this back to the original files?

Comment: This buffer stream is the raw content of the file, the same content you sent to S3, so just write it back on a file with the same name as the original one and it should just work fine.